# Removing Duplicates and adjacent cell in Excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlrd

[Table after column deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzuIC.jpg)I have an excel file that records the time someone logs in.
However if they have technical issues they have to log out and back in again.

How would I remove duplicates after the first instance in column A, but also remove the ajacent cell in column B?

Here is what I have so far to remove the columns I no longer need.

```
import pyexcel as p

p.save_book_as(file_name= latest_file,
           dest_file_name= NF_Name)
NF_Name = r'C:\Users\LouisKempson\Downloads\Sign_In_Summary_' + xcel_title_ + '_' + current_time + 
'.xlsx'
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = NF_Name)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws['A18'].value)
ws.delete_cols(1, 1)
ws.delete_cols(2, 5)
ws.delete_cols(3, 8)
wb.save(NF_Name)
print(ws['A18'].value)
```

Many Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and show, **how** do you decide which Column is ***duplicates***. Are you aware that `delete_cols` will affect **ALL** Rows?

Comment: No there are additional columns in the spreadsheet that I do not need. This is not where the duplicates are. The duplicates are in column A which is the login name. Column B is a list of login times. I need to fetch the first instance of each name in column A.

Comment: Still don't get it. [Edit] your question and extend to [mcve], show at least 3 Rows with 3 Columns of data. Show also your expected goal.